# Android MQTT client app not receiving publications when app paused then resumed

Tags: java, android, service, client, mqtt

MQTT Paho Client v3.3.1

MQTT Android Service v1.1.0

All publications are received when the application has focus. When the application loses focus or the mobile device goes to idle the publications are still received by the MQTT Android Service but they are stored in a local database.

I would expect these stored messages to be passed to the application when it resumes but they are not. I can publish new messages and they are received but the stored messages remain in the local database - **DatabaseMessageStore.java** class. The only way to get them to be sent by the Android Service is to 
disconnect and then reconnect.

I have found the code that passes on the stored publications in the service code class **MqttConnection.java**

```
private void deliverBacklog() {
    Iterator<StoredMessage> backlog = service.messageStore
            .getAllArrivedMessages(clientHandle);
    while (backlog.hasNext()) {
        StoredMessage msgArrived = backlog.next();
        Bundle resultBundle = messageToBundle(msgArrived.getMessageId(),
                msgArrived.getTopic(), msgArrived.getMessage());
        resultBundle.putString(MqttServiceConstants.CALLBACK_ACTION,
                MqttServiceConstants.MESSAGE_ARRIVED_ACTION);
        service.callbackToActivity(clientHandle, Status.OK, resultBundle);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway that I can call this when my application resumes?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android BroadcastReceiver.

> A broadcast receiver (receiver) is an Android component which allows
>   you to register for system or application events. All registered
>   receivers for an event are notified by the Android runtime once this
>   event happens.
>
> For example, applications can register for the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
>   system event which is fired once the Android system has completed the
>   boot process.

For implementation please go through this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html